# Convert PictureBox Selection Rectangle according to SizeMode

Tags: c#, selection, picturebox, coordinate-systems

I have two `PictureBoxes` pbOriginal and pbFace. After Selecting a "face" from an image in pbOriginal I clone the rectangle selection and place it into pbFace.
However, Because pbOriginal is using `SelectionMode=Stretch`  the actual area being copied is not the same as the area being selected.

**How do I convert the coordinates of the Rectangle so that they truly reflect the coordinates of the Stretched Image?**

Comment: You can get the stretch factors for Width and Height by dividing the pb.Image.Size.xx by the pb.ClienteSize.xx. You will have to do this for both the X&Y of the frame and the Width&Height.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: From what I know that is the consensus - but it is not a rule. I am on the side that disagree.

Comment: Usually the language and target Tags should __not__ be in the tilte, like`C#` and `WinForms` or `ASP`... OTOH the main topic like `PictureBox` or `Chart` should,. As we can filter by the tags imo the rule is: 'Will keyword usually be used as a filter?'

Comment: However, it is NOT a rule and therefore up to me whether I choose to add a lang tag to the title or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example that draws the second rectangle right along as you draw the first one..:

[image]

```
Point mDown = Point.Empty;
Point mCurr = Point.Empty;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   mDown = e.Location;  }

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
       { mCurr = e.Location; pictureBox1.Invalidate(); }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(mDown.X, mDown.Y, mCurr.X - mDown.X, mCurr.Y - mDown.Y);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Orange, r);
    pictureBox2.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox2.Image == null) return;

    float stretch1X = 1f * pictureBox1.Image.Width / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
    float stretch1Y = 1f * pictureBox1.Image.Height / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;

    int x = (int)(mDown.X * stretch1X);
    int y = (int)(mDown.Y * stretch1Y);
    int x2 = (int)(mCurr.X * stretch1X);
    int y2 = (int)(mCurr.Y * stretch1Y);

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, x2 - x, y2 - y);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Orange, r);
}
```

Note that it assumes that you are drawing top-left to bottom-right..

If you want to copy the selection you can use the same factors and the same `Rectangle` as the source for a `DrawImage` call:

```
float stretch1X = 1f * pictureBox1.Image.Width / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
float stretch1Y = 1f * pictureBox1.Image.Height / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;

Point pt = new Point((int)(mDown.X * stretch1X), (int)(mDown.Y * stretch1Y));
Size sz = new Size((int)((mCurr.X - mDown.X) * stretch1X), 
                   (int)((mCurr.Y - mDown.Y) * stretch1Y));


Rectangle rSrc = new Rectangle(pt, sz);
Rectangle rDest= new Rectangle(Point.Empty, sz);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height);
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    G.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, rDest, rSrc , GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
```

You may want to code the `MouseUp` event to store the finla `mCurr` position and trgger the copying..

Comment: It's not really what I asked - but I shall see if I can decypher the code to get it to do what I want. If I can I will give you the answer click

Comment: Your  pbOriginal is my picturebbox1 and  pbFace is my picturebbox2. - Oh, now I understand: your are copying the pixels, not just the rectangle? You can use the very same rectangle as source..  I have updated the answer..

Comment: what would the calculation be if the PictureBox was set to Zoom? And how did you work these calculations out?

Comment: Do you mean pbOriginal is in Zoom? It should work just the same. Image has always the actual, real number of pixels in the Image. ClientSize is the visible area of a Control. The difference between stretch and zoom is that zoom preserves the aspect ration, stretch doesn't. Since I calculate the factors for y and y separately it should always work..

Comment: when pbOriginal is in Zoom mode, the selection is made and showin in pbFace which is also in Zoom mode. The image shown in pbFace is much more narrow than it is shown in pbOriginal's selection.

Comment: Well, if both are in zoom mode you will have to do another round of calculation, this time with the 2nd pbs factors and dividing them instead of multiplying when calcualtion x&y or pt&sz..