# Translating a Point(X,Y) for Images of Different Sizes from a Custom PictureBox Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing

I have to process several images in bulk.I have to place some text at a particular point(X, Y).There is a custom control that is derived from picturebox that allows the user to drag the text and place it at the desired location.

There are two types of images for which I set the `PictureBoxSizeMode` differently

**Vertical Images**

[image]

I set > `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;`

**Horizontal**

For Horizontal Images that fill up the PictureBox i set > `PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage`

[image]

The user can select the location to place the text by dragging the text over this picturebox control.The original image is resized to the control size(for horizontal images) and the user drags the text over this image.

Based on the SizeMode of the Picturebox the selected point is translated to point within the original image using the following code

```
    if (sizemode == 1)
    {

     transpoint = TranslateStretchImageMousePosition(new Point(e.X - 20, e.Y -20));

    }

    else if (sizemode == 2)
    {
        transpoint = TranslateZoomMousePosition(new Point(e.X - 20, e.Y - 20));

    }

public Point TranslateStretchImageMousePosition(Point coordinates)
        {
            // test to make sure our image is not null
            if (Image == null) return coordinates;
            // Make sure our control width and height are not 0
            if (Width == 0 || Height == 0) return coordinates;
            // First, get the ratio (image to control) the height and width
            float ratioWidth = (float)Image.Width / Width;
            //MessageBox.Show(ratioWidth.ToString());

            float ratioHeight = (float)Image.Height / Height;
           // MessageBox.Show(ratioHeight.ToString());
            // Scale the points by our ratio
            float newX = coordinates.X;
            float newY = coordinates.Y;
            newX *= ratioWidth;
            newY *= ratioHeight;
            return new Point((int)newX, (int)newY);
        }

public Point TranslateZoomMousePosition(Point coordinates)
        {
            // test to make sure our image is not null
            if (Image == null) return coordinates;
            // Make sure our control width and height are not 0 and our 
            // image width and height are not 0
            if (Width == 0 || Height == 0 || Image.Width == 0 || Image.Height == 0) return coordinates;
            // This is the one that gets a little tricky. Essentially, need to check 
            // the aspect ratio of the image to the aspect ratio of the control
            // to determine how it is being rendered
            float imageAspect = (float)Image.Width / Image.Height;
            float controlAspect = (float)Width / Height;
            float newX = coordinates.X;
            float newY = coordinates.Y;
            if (imageAspect > controlAspect)
            {
                // This means that we are limited by width, 
                // meaning the image fills up the entire control from left to right
                float ratioWidth = (float)Image.Width / Width;
                newX *= ratioWidth;
                float scale = (float)Width / Image.Width;
                float displayHeight = scale * Image.Height;
                float diffHeight = Height - displayHeight;
                diffHeight /= 2;
                newY -= diffHeight;
                newY /= scale;
            }
            else
            {
                // This means that we are limited by height, 
                // meaning the image fills up the entire control from top to bottom
                float ratioHeight = (float)Image.Height / Height;
                newY *= ratioHeight;
                float scale = (float)Height / Image.Height;
                float displayWidth = scale * Image.Width;
                float diffWidth = Width - displayWidth;
                diffWidth /= 2;
                newX -= diffWidth;
                newX /= scale;
            }
            return new Point((int)newX, (int)newY);
        }
```

---

Now after getting the Point I have to call another method within the Main Form to get the approximate text location

```
    point= translatemanualpoint(transpoint, img, refimgsize.Width, refimgsize.Height);
```

Where `refimgsize` is the size of the original image(unscaled) used to place the text.

```
 private Point translatemanualpoint(Point coordinates, Bitmap Image, int Width, int Height)
        {

            //---------------------------------
            // test to make sure our image is not null
            if (Image == null) return coordinates;
            // Make sure our control width and height are not 0
            if (Width == 0 || Height == 0) return coordinates;
            // First, get the ratio (image to control) the height and width
            float ratioWidth = (float)Image.Width / Width;


            float ratioHeight = (float)Image.Height / Height;

            // Scale the points by our ratio
            float newX = coordinates.X;
            float newY = coordinates.Y;
            newX *= ratioWidth;
            newY *= ratioHeight;
            return new Point((int)newX, (int)newY);  

        }
```

**The problem is that this method is not accurate.When I use a Horizontal Image as reference to place the Text and when the point is translated to a point in the vertical image;the position of the point is not correct.Same thing happens when i use a vertical Image as reference and translation is done to  a point in the Horizontal Image**

What I'm I doing wrong?Please advice.

Please let me know if I need to post the full code of the control.

**UPDATE:**

This is what i want to achieve.The Logo and the Text in the pictures below are manually placed.You can see that how the logo and the text appears in approximately same locations in images of different aspect ratios.

***UPDATE:***
As per @Taw's comments i have taken the following approach to find the 2 closest edges and use the respective spacing.

```
void findclosestedges(Point p)
        {         

            //Xedge=1 -- Left Edge is closer to Point 2--Right Edge 

            //Finding closest Left/Right Edge
            if (p.X < (ClientSize.Width - p.X))
            {

                LaunchOrigin.Xedge = 1;
                LaunchOrigin.Xspacing = p.X;
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = " ";
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " left";
            }
            else
            {
                LaunchOrigin.Xedge = 2;
                LaunchOrigin.Xspacing = (ClientSize.Width - p.X);
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = " ";
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " right";
            }

            //Finding closest Top/Bottom Edge

            if (p.Y < (ClientSize.Height - p.Y))
            {
                LaunchOrigin.Yedge = 1;
                LaunchOrigin.Yspacing =p.Y;
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " top";
            }
            else
            {
                LaunchOrigin.Yedge = 2;
                LaunchOrigin.Yspacing = (ClientSize.Height - p.Y);
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " bottom";
            }
            LaunchOrigin.ewidth = Width;
            LaunchOrigin.eheight = Height;
        }
```

---

Now in the Main Form i do the following

```
  int wratio = img.Width / ewidth;
    int hratio = img.Height / eheight;
    if (Xedge == 1)
    {

            cpoint.X = Xspacing*wratio;


    }
    else
    {

        cpoint.X = img.Width - Xspacing * wratio;



    }
    if (Yedge == 1)
    {

        cpoint.Y = Yspacing * hratio;




    }
    else
    {


            cpoint.Y = img.Height - Yspacing*hratio;


    }
```

Still i don't get the proper positioning.

What i'm i doing wrong?

This is what i want to achieve...

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

As per @Abion47 answer i have used the following approach

In the custom picturebox control

```
Point src = e.Location;
PointF ratio = new PointF((float)src.X / Width, (float)src.Y / Height);
LaunchOrigin.ratio = ratio;
Point origin = new Point((int)(backupbit1.Width * ratio.X), (int)(backupbit1.Height * ratio.Y));
LaunchOrigin.origin = origin;
point.X = src.X - origin.X;
point.Y = src.Y - origin.Y;
```

In the Main window

```
Point pos2 = new Point((int)(ratio.X * img.Width), (int)(ratio.Y * img.Height));
cpoint.X = pos2.X  - origin.X;
cpoint.Y = pos2.Y  - origin.Y;
```

This works almost okay.. except the Bottom-Right edge.

In the custom picture-box

[image]

In in the Main form

[image]

What i'm i doing wrong? Please advice.

***UPDATE:***

What i have done is calculate the ratio from the picturebox control and use the ratio like this in the Main form to translate the point

```
Point origin = new Point((int)(bitmap.Width * textratio.X), (int)(bitmap.Height * textratio.Y));
Point pos2 = new Point((int)(textratio.X * img.Width), (int)(textratio.Y * img.Height));
cpoint.X = pos2.X - (int)(origin.X);
cpoint.Y = pos2.Y - (int)(origin.Y);
```

For the Logo i do the same like this

```
Point origin = new Point((int)(worktag.Width * logoratio.X), (int)(worktag.Height * logoratio.Y));
Point logopositionpoint = new Point((int)(logoratio.X * img.Width), (int)(logoratio.Y * img.Height));
imgpoint.X = logopositionpoint.X - origin.X;
imgpoint.Y = logopositionpoint.Y - origin.Y;
```

This works pretty well until i place the text and logo closely.In the custom picturebox control text and logo appears correctly.In the Main window,For vertical images they appear alright,but for horizontal images both overlaps... What's going wrong here? Please advice..

***UPDATE***

This works well.But how do i translate the point from the Main window to the custom picturebox control( with the text that allows dragging).

I have tried the following code.But this is not giving precise positioning

```
  private Point translatetextpoint(Point mpoint,Bitmap bitmap)
        {

            PointF ratio = new PointF((float)LaunchOrigin.cpoint.X /LaunchOrigin.img.Width, (float)LaunchOrigin.cpoint.Y /LaunchOrigin.img.Height);
            Point origin = new Point((int)(endPointPictureBox1.bit.Width * ratio.X), (int)(endPointPictureBox1.bit.Height * ratio.Y));
            Point pos2 = new Point((int)(ratio.X * endPointPictureBox1.Width), (int)(ratio.Y * endPointPictureBox1
                .Height));
            pos2.X = pos2.X - (int)(origin.X);
            pos2.Y = pos2.Y - (int)(origin.Y);
            return pos2;
        }
```

Please advice..

Comment: hmm .. why is this question downvoted? Any comments would be useful..

Comment: Is it a class? If so using ClientSize.Height over Height  is preferred as it will allow borders.. One possible downvote (not mine) reason could be lack of research as the question is not exactly new..

Comment: @TaW can we continue this discussion on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143591/system-drawing

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd say it's because your question is a wall of text/code without a clear statement of what your problem actually is.

Comment: @Abion47 Please see the update..

Comment: My question to you is why would you be using a vertical image as a reference to a horizontal image's layout (or vice versa)? That seems like a potential design problem right there.

Comment: @TaW Its a Class... i don't understand why i need to use `ClientSize.Height` .. will it fix the issue.

Comment: @Abion47 Say.. if the user needs to place the text at a particular location in the vertical image...so.. i have no other option.

Comment: You aren't explaining your use case very well (or hardly at all). ***Why*** would the user use a horizontal image as a reference point if they are positioning text on a vertical image??? Why not use a ***vertical*** image as a reference???

Comment: @Abion47 The images are processed in bulk.so the user can select any image from the collection(includes vertical and horizontal)as the reference and the place text.Basically i need to make sure the text appears at the (approximate) same  location in all images.. after the final processing.

Comment: You should be storing your point internally as a ratio instead of a discrete point, then. When you set a reference, set X and Y as a value from 0.0 to 1.0, which is the reference point's X and Y divided by the reference image's width and height, respectively. Then when you apply it to a target image, multiply the reference point by the target image's width and height to get your scaled point. It's basically a simplified version of what you are already doing, but consolidating your math will make your code less error-prone.

Comment: Some examples are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436313/convert-picturebox-selection-rectangle-according-to-sizemode/30437608#30437608) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027931/how-to-control-position-of-label-or-any-control-picturebox/35033334#35033334) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303881/how-to-draw-on-a-zoomed-image/39305038#39305038).. You can use Height and Width if (and only if!) the PBox has no borders.

Comment: @TaW Tried with `ClientSize.Width` and `ClientSize.Height`.Still the issue remains unresolved.Is there any easier and better approach in dealing with this problem?

Comment: @Abion47 Can you please post some sample code..

Comment: I'm not sure if you have one or two issues here. Maybe there are problems with the calculations; I don't have time to dive into your code. The links I provided should cover all cases. But maybe the real issue is the design. What would it mean for the user to drag text to a spot on one image and expect the text to be placed to 'the same' spot on other images of different sizes and ratios??? The same pixel position (1) or the same position proportionally, like always in the middle or always at (10%;5%) (2) or maybe 'top right+ (-20px; 10px)' (3) or what??

Comment: @TaW The user can drag and place the text wherever he/she wishes.I dont need the exact pixel specific location.I just need the approximate location.Currently if the user chooses to place the text at the bottom corner of a vertical image,when it comes to horizontal images.. the text goes off the image..

Comment: @TaW Also the Image is being resized to fit in the custom picturebox control.. that is why i store the unscaled reference image size in `refimgsize`

Comment: a) if the text ever goes off your calculation is wrong somehow. b) you really need to understand more clearly what you want. I assume that you want to add the text at the same __proportional__ position. This means: You first need to do two calculations: 1st go from pbox mouse position to image position and then also 2nd: calculate the proprtional position from image position. Once you have this pro.Pos. you can use it for all other images..Think of a propPos as percentages, not as pixels.

Comment: To reiterate: You need to know what you want! You keep writing about 'the same position'. But there is no such thing! 'position' is not a clearly defined thing: It can be a) absolute in pixels b) absolute in percent or c) relative in various ways. Examples: Always at (50, 50) Always at (50%, 50%) Always at (50,50) from the lower right corner. Now: For a 100x100 image they are all the same. But for a 500x1000 image they become (50,50), (250, 500) and (450, 950). No way to write code without a clearly defined goal!

Comment: . - Want another plausible rule: (10%,10%) from the lower left corner. One more: Some percentage but clamped from 20 to 100 pixels. etc, etc..

Comment: @TaW Found a solution to fix the issue to an extend...so closing the question.. thanks

Comment: @TaW Undeleted.... issue still exists :(

Comment: @TaW Please see the update..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143674/discussion-between-taw-and-techno).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't read through all your code to tell you exactly how you should code this, but here is some example code as a possibility:

```
PointF GetReferencePoint(Point absoluteReferencePoint)
{
    PointF referencePointAsRatio = new Point();

    referencePointAsRatio.X = (float)absoluteReferencePoint.X / referenceImage.Width;
    referencePointAsRatio.Y = (float)absoluteReferencePoint.Y / referenceImage.Height;

    return referencePointAsRatio;
}

...

Point GetTargetPoint(PointF referencePointAsRatio)
{
    Point targetPoint = new Point();

    targetPoint.X = (int)(referencePointAsRatio.X * targetImage.Width);
    targetPoint.Y = (int)(referencePointAsRatio.Y * targetImage.Height);

    return targetPoint;
}
```

In your practice, you will probably need to do some offsetting as well to account for border thicknesses or whatever.

**EDIT:**

One thing you can possibly do to "correct" the position is to offset the positions of the text elements depending on where they are in the image. For example, text in the top left corner will be positioned relative to its own top left corner, those in the lower right will be positioned to their own lower right, and those in the center of the image will be positioned relative to their center.

Building off of the example I gave in my sample project (download link in the comments), you can do it like so:

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point src = e.Location;
    PointF ratio = new PointF((float)src.X / pictureBox1.Width, (float)src.Y / pictureBox1.Height);
    Point origin = new Point((int)(label1.Width * ratio.X), (int)(label1.Height * ratio.Y));

    label1.Left = src.X - origin.X;
    label1.Top = src.Y - origin.Y;

    Point pos2 = new Point((int)(ratio.X * pictureBox2.Width), (int)(ratio.Y * pictureBox2.Height));
    label2.Left = pos2.X + pictureBox2.Left - origin.X;
    label2.Top = pos2.Y + pictureBox2.Top - origin.Y;

    Point pos3 = new Point((int)(ratio.X * pictureBox3.Width), (int)(ratio.Y * pictureBox3.Height));
    label3.Left = pos3.X + pictureBox3.Left - origin.X;
    label3.Top = pos3.Y + pictureBox3.Top - origin.Y;

    Point pos4 = new Point((int)(ratio.X * pictureBox4.Width), (int)(ratio.Y * pictureBox4.Height));
    label4.Left = pos4.X + pictureBox4.Left - origin.X;
    label4.Top = pos4.Y + pictureBox4.Top - origin.Y;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please see my latest update... Ran into a new problem.

Comment: @techno Then you'll have to do some [overlap detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0(v=vs.110).aspx) and offset the resulting positions so they don't overlap anymore.

Comment: How do you suggest i do this? Please advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018201/performing-overlap-detection-of-2-bitmaps

Comment: I have successfully got over the intersection issue.There exists one more problem that i need your help with.How can i translate the point from the Main window to the custom picturebox control.Please see my Latest Update.I really appreciate your help..

Comment: @techno I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you trying to convert the point from being relative to the picture box to being relative to the main window?

Comment: I have a Point within a Picture (where the text is drawn).I want to convert this point to a point within the custom picturebox control (on another form) so that i can place the text(as a bitmap) at that point and allow the user to select and drag the text. The selected position is translated back to the Main form using the Logic you have already provided. Hope you got an idea now..