# Offsetting Rectangle Positions to prevent overlap

Tags: c#, bitmap, geometry, gdi+, system.drawing

I have the following cases where rectangles overlap.
[image]

I have the coordinates for the intersection rectangle(Blue).
How can i offset the starting coordinates(top-left X-Y) of the 2 rectangles to prevent overlapping,provided that i have the coordinates of the intersection rectangle using

```
rectangle3 = Rectangle.Intersect(rectangle1, rectangle2);
```

**UPDATE:**

As per @MBo 's Update i have added the following code

```
Blue = Rectangle.Intersect(First, Second);
if (Blue != Rectangle.Empty)
{
if (First.Right == Blue.Right)
{

imgpoint.X += (Blue.Right - Blue.Left);
}

if (First.Bottom == Blue.Bottom)
{
imgpoint.Y += (Blue.Bottom - Blue.Top);
}

if (First.Left == Blue.Left)
{
imgpoint.X-= (Blue.Right - Blue.Left);
}
if (First.Top == Blue.Top)
{
imgpoint.Y -= (Blue.Bottom - Blue.Top);
}
}
```

***UPDATE2:***

As per @MBo 's Logic i implemented the code above.This works in most cases.But in some images even when the intesection is detected and the offset is added i get overlapping.See the sample image below.

The actual problem i'm trying to solve is linked to these 2 questions
[Translating a Point(X,Y) for Images of Different Sizes from a Custom PictureBox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828381/translating-a-pointx-y-for-images-of-different-sizes-from-a-custom-picturebox/)

[Performing Overlap Detection of 2 Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018201/performing-overlap-detection-of-2-bitmaps/)

Please advice.

**UPDATE:**[image]

UPDATE:

As per your update i have translated the Delphi code to C#

```
Blue = Rectangle.Intersect(First, Second);
if (Blue != Rectangle.Empty)
{
int dcy,dcx;
int dy,dx;
int fl=First.Left,fw=First.Width,fh=First.Height,ft=First.Top,fb=First.Bottom,fr=First.Right;
int sl=Second.Left,sr=Second.Right,st=Second.Top,sb=Second.Bottom,sw=Second.Width,sh=Second.Height;
dcy = (sb + st) - (fb + ft);  //doubled center y-difference
dcx = (sl + sr) - (fl + fr);
if ((int)(dcx) >= (fw + sw) || ((int)(dcy) >= (fh + sh)))
{//no intersection

}
else
{

dx = fw + sw - (int)dcx;  //doubled  needed x-shift absolute value
dy = fh + sh - (int)dcy;

if (dx > dy)
{
if (dcy < 0)
{
dy = - dy/2;
}
else
{
dy = dy/ 2;  //needed y-shift accounting for direction
}
dx = 0;
}
else 
{
if (dcy < 0)
{
dx =  - dx/ 2;
}
else
{
dx =  dx/2;
dy = 0;
}
}
imgpoint.X+=dx;
imgpoint.Y+=dy;
}
}
```

While using this code the Second Image gets moved too far in some cases.Please let me know if the code is right.

[image]

Comment: You are using `(int)(dcx)` and dcy in two places where absolute value is needed (something like `math.abs`)

Comment: @MBo Thanks.Will check and get back.

Comment: @MBo Thanks a lot :) Your second update works great after using `Math.Abs`.Really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Checked all possible cases, had got the next simple code (Delphi code, works).

```
//fl, fw, fr, ft, fh, fb: First.Left, Width, Right, Top, Height, Bottom
//s* - similar parameters for the second rectangle   


dcy := (sb + st) - (fb + ft);  //doubled center y-difference
dcx := (sl + sr) - (fl + fr);
if (Abs(dcx) >= fw + sw) or ((Abs(dcy) >= fh + sh)) then  //no intersection
  Exit;

dx := fw + sw - Abs(dcx);  //doubled  needed x-shift absolute value
dy := fh + sh - Abs(dcy);

 if dx > dy then begin
   if dcy < 0 then
      dy := - dy div 2
   else
      dy := dy div 2;  //needed y-shift accounting for direction
   dx := 0;
 end else begin
   if dcy < 0 then
      dx :=  - dx div 2
   else
      dx :=  dx div 2;
   dy := 0;
 end;

//Result: dx, dy pair to shift the second rectangle
```

[Full code](http://ideone.com/xaOwRn)

---

Old answer for temporary reference:

You need information - what coordinate of the first rectangle coincides with corresponding coordinate of intersection rectangle. For simple intersection cases:

```
case
   First.Right = Blue.Right:   
      shift Second.Left by (Blue.Right - Blue.Left)
   First.Bottom = Blue.Bottom:
      shift Second.Top by (Blue.Bottom - Blue.Top)
   First.Left = Blue.Left:
      shift Second.Left by  -(Blue.Right - Blue.Left)
   First.Top = Blue.Top:
      shift Second.Top by -(Blue.Bottom - Blue.Top)
```

Edit:
If intersection exists and none of cases above is met, then full inclusion and cross-like intersection takes place. So determine what is the shortest way to avoid overlap:

```
 dcy = (Second.Bottom + Second.Top) - (First.Bottom + First.Top)   
 if dcy >=0 then
      shift Second.Top by (First.Bottom - Second.Top)   //down
 else
      shift Second.Top by -(Second.Bottom - First.Top)   //up

 dcx = (Second.Left + Second.Right) - (First.Left + First.Right)   
 if dcx >=0 then
      shift Second.Left by (First.Right - Second.Left)   //right
 else
      shift Second.Left by -(Second.Right - First.Left)   //left
```

Comment: Thanks.. but what if `Blue` has two intersection edges..?

Comment: This works for corner-corner case (two conditions). About more complex cases (cross etc)- you wrote "I have the following cases". Shift left is provided with minus sign here` -(Blue.Right - Blue.Left)`

Comment: My Bad.. Missed the Minus Sign... If possible ..Could you please take a look at this question,im asking this question to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018201/performing-overlap-detection-of-2-bitmaps

Comment: I have implemented your logic in my code and it works pretty well.Please check my update and see if something is wrong.

Comment: Looks right. (If you don't need cases of full inclusion and cross-like intersection)

Comment: Please see my update.Even when overlap detection code is hit.There is overlapping in some cases.

Comment: See my addition

Comment: I have seen your addition.There exits a case where intersection is found and all 4 if conditions are met.I have implemented your logic as `if` condition statements and not `switch case`.So since all 4 `if` blocks are hit,when will your new logic be applicable? Please see the update.Please advice.

Comment: Sorry.. i was not notified about your edit.. will check and get back.

Comment: I have reused your first answer and after an error correction on my side(forgot to trim the whitespaces, as i did the same early) it works fine.As i have told you earlier i have implemented this as an `if` block of code ,hope its right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the r2(rectangle2) if between r2.X and r2.X+r2.Height or between r2.Y and r2.Y + r2.Y+r2.Width or not betwwen us and make changes 
I writed a sample code

```
private int GetNewX(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
   if (r2.X < r1.X)
   {
       return r1.X - r2.Width;
   }
   else
   {
       return r1.X + r1.Width;
   }
}
private int GetNewY(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
   if (r2.Y < r1.Y)
   {
       return r1.Y - r2.Height;
   }
   else
   {
       return r1.Y + r1.Height;
   }
}

Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(60, 10, 200, 200);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(40, 25, 200, 160);


//If overlapped change X,Y of the r2 rectangle
Rectangle overlapRect = Rectangle.Intersect(r1, r2);
if (overlapRect.Width > 0 || overlapRect.Height > 0)
{
    bool betweenX = overlapRect.X >= r1.X && overlapRect.X <= (r1.X + r1.Height);
    bool betweenY = overlapRect.Y >= r1.Y && overlapRect.Y <= (r1.Y + r1.Width);

    if (betweenX)
    {
        r2.X = GetNewX(r1,r2);                    
    }
    else if (betweenY)
    {
        r2.Y = GetNewY(r1, r2);
    }
    else
    {
        if (overlapRect.Width <= overlapRect.Height)
        {
            r2.X = GetNewX(r1, r2);
        }
        else
        {
            r2.Y = GetNewY(r1, r2);
        }
    }                
}

Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawRectangle(pen, r1);
g.DrawRectangle(pen, r2);
```

Comment: you are welcome @techno. Please get back if u have any problem. Please note I used my code on a Form

Comment: will do.thanks :) . Do you mean you have tested the code on your form...

Comment: okay.. thanks... will test on my use case and get back.. what i'm actually trying to solve using this question is this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018201/performing-overlap-detection-of-2-bitmaps

Comment: @techno you can use the same technique if u have 2 bitmaps coordinates and their width and height. If u can't solve please write me. If I can I'll help you

Comment: @techno I created a sample on a form for you which accepts 2 images and not ovelapping. See the asnwer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018201/performing-overlap-detection-of-2-bitmaps

Comment: This prevents overlapping,but changes the rectangle position significantly.i just need to offset the second point ..so that it does not overlap..

Comment: @techno I will fix it

Comment: @techno do you fixed the problem ?

Comment: @techno sorry fore my late response because I'm full these days :(

Comment: No Problem :) Thanks for your help.