# How can I properly crop part of an image?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to crop an image, but the image doesn't get cropped properly

The code I'm using to get part of the picture I want is

```
Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
Bitmap cropImg = new Bitmap(cropArea.Width, cropArea.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cropImg);
g.DrawImage(bmap, 0, 0, cropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
return cropImg;
```

the result I get is weird

Crop Reuslt :

[image: crop result]

The cropped picture gets blurred and zoomed in(?). What could be the cause the problem and what could I do to get rid of it?

Comment: It seems the code is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/734930/1997232). What is `cropArea`? It seems you are not calculating rectangle vertical offset and height correctly.

Comment: cropArea is the rectangle that represents the selected area

Comment: Depending on the SizeMode you will have to do a of calculating to scale the mousecoordinates to suit the pb sizemode. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436313/convert-picturebox-selection-rectangle-according-to-sizemode/30437608?r=SearchResults&s=1|57.7281#30437608)

Comment: @TaW

I've been playing with the sample you provided, but still can't get the crop function to work properly :( 

https://imgur.com/a/OCWWlYi


crop method code: https://imgur.com/a/yVMgaW4

Comment: Whart sizemode is the pbox in?

Comment: @TaW it's Squeeze

Comment: I've changed the mode to 'Stretch' and it seems to work as expected. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Good to hear. It wasn't really in 'Squeeze' mode, right ;-)

Comment: How can I calculate it so it works with zoom mode? I need to let the user zoom in/out and still crop the correct part of picture @TaW

Comment: Explain exactly how the user zooms!

Comment: @TaW I have an UI control that lets the user zoom based on percentage like this https://i.imgur.com/8ebTHkx.jpg

Comment: I didn't mean the UI; I meant how do you realize it in your picturebox? Do you change the pbox.Size? Is it embedded in a Panel?

Answer (score 0):

You can try crop by cloning the original image, but only taking a rectangle of the original.

```
private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
   Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
   Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
   bmpImage.PixelFormat);
   return (Image)(bmpCrop);
}
```

Comment: Well, the result is different now. The image doesn't get blurry anymore, but still doesn't get cropped correctly

https://imgur.com/a/m2clOy4

Comment: @bapster that's because of `cropArea` values you need to do a calculation that match the desired output

Comment: How can I calculate it then? Can you specify?

Comment: @bapster you can get a look into this [post](https://alex.domenici.net/archive/resize-and-crop-an-image-keeping-its-aspect-ratio-with-c-sharp) and see how to handle the aspect ratio