# Crop correct part of image while the PictureBox is in 'zoom' mode

Tags: c#

I have a PictureBox1 with it's sizemode set to Stretch and PictureBox1. The PictureBox1 contains an image and let's me select part of it and then crop it and store the cropped part inside PictureBox2. It works great **when the sizemode is set to Stretch and the picture is not zoomed**, but not when I zoom it or set the sizemode to zoom.

[working example - sizemode set to 'stretch'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEd2c.jpg)

The code I use to crop part of the picture ([original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436313/convert-picturebox-selection-rectangle-according-to-sizemode/30437608#30437608))

```
try
{
    float stretch1X = 1f * pictureBox1.Image.Width / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
    float stretch1Y = 1f * pictureBox1.Image.Height / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;

    Point pt = new Point((int)(_mDown.X * stretch1X), (int)(_mDown.Y * stretch1Y));
    Size sz = new Size((int)((_mCurr.X - _mDown.X) * stretch1X),
                       (int)((_mCurr.Y - _mDown.Y) * stretch1Y));



    if (sz.Width > 0 && sz.Height > 0)
    {
        Rectangle rSrc = new Rectangle(pt, sz);
        Rectangle rDest = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, sz);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height);
        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            G.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, rDest, rSrc, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        return bmp;
    }

    return null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

How do I calculate it properly? How can I make the crop function work in a way so it lets the user zoom in/out and still crop the correct part of the picture?

Comment: When it is zoomed then stretch1X == stretch1Y.  [Look here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,5c2ab37313f547c2).

Comment: How could I apply this to my scenario? Could you explain a little more? Your explanation is not quite clear to me @HansPassant

Comment: You need to know the size of the displayed image, that method calculates it.  Just duplicate the code for the zoom case.  Once you know that size you can divide it by the image.Width to know stretch1X.  And thus stretch1Y.  The displayed image will be letter-boxed horizontally or vertically, offset by the difference between the displayed image size and the PictureBox.ClientSize, divided by 2.

Comment: This is a little confusing, can you post some hint code based on the code I posted above? Thanks in advance @HansPassant

Comment: @Hans: You are quite right ! Funny how I couldn't find that post..!? I leave the answer because it also creates the cropped image and demonstrates that it also works in zoomed mode..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to calculate the points using the stretch factor and maybe also the offset.

For `Zoom` there is only **one** factor as aspect ratio is always the same for `Image` and `PictureBox`, but there usually is an **offset**; for `Stretch` you need no offset but **two** factors.

Here is an example that goes all the way using **two** `PictureBoxes` two show a zoomed version and the cropped bitmap. It makes use of an all-purpose function `ImageArea` that determines size and offset.

[image]

Two class level variables:

```
Point pDown = Point.Empty;
Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Empty;
```

Three mouse events:

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pDown = e.Location;
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}

private void PictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left)) return;

    rect = new Rectangle(pDown, new Size(e.X - pDown.X, e.Y - pDown.Y));
    using (Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Orange, rect);
    }
}

private void PictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle iR = ImageArea(pictureBox2);
    rect = new Rectangle(pDown.X - iR.X, pDown.Y - iR.Y, 
                         e.X - pDown.X, e.Y - pDown.Y);
    Rectangle rectSrc = Scaled(rect, pictureBox2, true);
    Rectangle rectDest = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, rectSrc.Size);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rectDest.Width, rectDest.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.DrawImage(pictureBox2.Image, rectDest, rectSrc, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
}
```

Here is a useful function that returns the area of the actual image inside a picturebox for any sizemode..:

```
Rectangle ImageArea(PictureBox pbox)
{
    Size si = pbox.Image.Size;
    Size sp = pbox.ClientSize;

    if (pbox.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage) 
       return pbox.ClientRectangle;
    if (pbox.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal ||
        pbox.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize) 
       return new Rectangle(Point.Empty, si);
    if (pbox.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage)
        return new Rectangle(new Point((sp.Width - si.Width) / 2,
                            (sp.Height - si.Height) / 2), si);

    //  PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    float ri = 1f * si.Width / si.Height;
    float rp = 1f * sp.Width / sp.Height;
    if (rp > ri)
    {
        int width = si.Width * sp.Height / si.Height;
        int left = (sp.Width - width) / 2;
        return new Rectangle(left, 0, width, sp.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        int height = si.Height * sp.Width / si.Width;
        int top = (sp.Height - height) / 2;
        return new Rectangle(0, top, sp.Width, height);
    }
}
```

We only need the offset to determine the rectangle unscaled. We also need to scale it:

```
Rectangle Scaled(Rectangle rect, PictureBox pbox, bool scale)
{
    float factor = GetFactor(pbox);
    if (!scale) factor = 1f / factor;
    return Rectangle.Round(new RectangleF(rect.X * factor, rect.Y * factor,  
                               rect.Width * factor, rect.Height * factor));
}
```

For this need to know the scaling factor, which depends on the aspect ratio:

```
float GetFactor(PictureBox pBox)
{
    if (pBox.Image == null) return 0;
    Size si = pBox.Image.Size;
    Size sp = pBox.ClientSize;
    float ri = 1f * si.Width / si.Height;
    float rp = 1f * sp.Width / sp.Height;
    float factor = 1f * pBox.Image.Width / pBox.ClientSize.Width;
    if (rp > ri) factor = 1f * pBox.Image.Height / pBox.ClientSize.Height;
    return factor;
}
```

This solution will also work if the `PictureBox` is **zoomed in or out** by placing it inside a `AutoScrolling Panel` and changing the `Pbox.Size`.